# Is it possible to reorder a XML element based on the siblings' attributes preferably with python?

Tags: python, xml

I have a XML file has only one type of element `<parameter>`. For simplicity, let's consider only three of such elements.

```
<parameter name="LengthA" value="1"/>
<parameter name="LengthB" value="2*LengthA"/>
<parameter name="LengthC" value="2*LengthB"/>
```

I'm using a program to parse this XML and calculate the numerical value for all parameters. For the above XML snippets, this program should be getting:

```
LengthA=1
LengthB=2
LengthC=4
```

However, what drives me crazy is that this program can only parse it line by line. That means if these three lines are written in the following order (notice LengthB is now ahead of LengthA):

```
<parameter name="LengthB" value="2*LengthA"/>
<parameter name="LengthA" value="1"/>
<parameter name="LengthC" value="2*LengthB"/>
```

the program will be not able to calculate `LengthB` and `LengthC` because it think `LengthA` is not defined when parsing the first line. My real XML file consists of more than 1000 lines and I can do nothing about this program. So I'm here asking for help of reordering such an out-of-order XML file (preferably using python script to solve this issue). And I don't care about execution time. Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: Why? If your XML has a hard ordering requirement, _generated ordered XML elements_? XML is a data transport format, it's pretty reasonable to assume you're not going to do your processing while you're still parsing your XML fragments. Presumably you don't have 1000 elements all nested at the same depth, all dependent on each other, so: read but don't process until you've finished reading whatever constitutes an atomic group of elements, _then_ do your processing? (in parallel to the stream reader continuing to feed data to whatever you wrote to ingest it?)

Comment: The old XML is parsed by an old program which doesn't care about ordering. Now  a new program is used and it unfortunately does care about the ordering. So I have to reorder the old XML into a new one. I agree this new program is stupid and don't process until finished reading all contents, but I have no control over this program.

Comment: An XML file consisting of ONLY three `<parameter.../>` elements is invalid. There must be a root element containing the `parameter` elements.  Also, reordering XML is best handled with an XSLT transformation.

Comment: Yes, there's a root element which is called <DDDB> but it doesn't matter in my context.

Comment: Don't reorder: capture the stream output in a reasonable data structure, and one that structure is complete (even if you're still stream reading), only _then_ start processing the data (for that now self-contained data structure). Schemas matter: what goes _around_ these elements? Is this, for example, a tree of mathematical expressions? If so, build the tree and start resolving it once you read leaf nodes, not "as the XML gets parsed".

Comment: Okay dude, thanks for being thoughtful and I wish I could control the way the program parses XML, but it is really a blackbox to me... I can't control the stream output of the program...

Comment: If there's no effective way to do this in XML-python manner, I think it could be done by writing a silly python script which reads my XML file by lines into a list. And I can reorder this list by some (perhaps complicated) condition statements. This is fine since I don't care about execution time.